# How to uninstall Intel Parallel Studio XE 2019 on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: software-uninstall

I have `Intel Parallel Studio XE 2019 Update 4` installed on my `Ubuntu 22.04` system. I want to uninstall it completely. I installed it several years ago but didn't it use much. I did some internet search but couldn't find something clear. How do I do it? Is there a way to do it from `Terminal`?

Comment: The best way to remove something, is to reverse how it was installed. You've not told us how you installed it on your system (*Ubuntu 22.04 LTS was released in April 2022, which was less than a year ago, have you looked for a command in your history, or package logs for clues? if you don't remember how you installed it?*)

Comment: @guiverc, thanks. I had installed it perhaps in 2019 when I was running Ubuntu 20.04. I had probably downloaded the installer and then I am not sure how I installed it. I never really used it and ended up forgetting pretty much everything about it. Now I am running low on my disk space and that's why I am uninstalling everything I haven't used in a very long time. Any suggestions on how I can figure this out if I need it or is there a workaround?

Comment: I have no experience with the software, thus my *comment* was generic.  I'd explore your logs for clues; including your command history (`history`, esp. if you use commands to install things; I do ), or your *apt* history (`/var/log/apt/history.log` ; if your history goes back years as mine does this file isn't fun, but it can be quickly searched if you're familiar with  command line, `vi` etc.).  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS was released in 2020-April (thus why it's 20.04; Ubuntu releases are *year.month* with 2000 added to *year*) so 2019?

Comment: Thanks again @guiverc. About the year 2019, I see! I guess I had installed Ubuntu in 2019 so it was perhaps the LTS version available at the time and therefore perhaps the version before 20.04. I probably upgraded a few months after 2019 when 20.04 became available. I usually install everything using commands after doing a Google search because I have limited Ubuntu skills. I am not familiar with logs and history but I will see if I can do something. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: From the Release Notes of that software: "*For instructions on installing and uninstalling the Intel® Parallel Studio XE see the Installation Guide for your operating system. These are available from the Intel® Software Development Products Registration Center page for Intel® Parallel Studio XE for your operating system.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out the answer and successfully uninstalled `Intel Parallel Studio XE 2019 Update 4` from my `Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS` system. I am posting my answer here in case it might help somebody who needed to do the same thing. One has to go to the directory where it's installed (in my case it was `/opt/intel/`). There are two `uninstall.sh` and `uninstall_GUI.sh` files there. Try running them (I managed to run `uninstall_GUI.sh`) and it will walk you through the uninstall process.